# Can I use dynamic imports to load test suite modules into mocha?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I have been structuring my tests with commonJs using the following structure;

```js
// My main file
describe('unit tests', function(){
   require('./unit/test.spec.js');
})
describe('functional tests', function(){
   require('./function/test.spec.js');
})

//... and soforth ...
```

My test.spec.js is along these lines;

```js
it('does something', function(){
    assert.equal(1,1);
})
```

In this way I can structure a large set of tests in seperate files, and it works well.

I am trying to do the same with ESM dynamic imports, like so;

```js
describe('functional tests', async function(){
   await import('./function/test.spec.js');
})

//... and soforth ...
```

The result however is now `0 passing (0ms)`.

It would appear that either Mocha is not triggering `describe`, or ESM is not running the imported code. Maybe there is a better approach? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one myself;

In short, the answer is "no", dynamic imports do not function as desired inside of a Mocha `describe` block.

You can however [dynamically generate](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests) the test suite using top-level imports. *(Node >= v14.8.0 with ESM test file)*

The suite generator file thus becomes;

```js
export default function(){
    it('does something', function(){
        assert.equal(1,1);
    })
}
```

and the top level main file;

```js
import suite from './unit/test.spec.js'; //top level import
describe('unit tests',suite);
```

All is now functioning as it was with commonJs before.